# What is the value of the BGR in OpenCV?

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv, opencv3.0

I know black is `[0,0,0]`,and white is `[255,255,255]`.

Red is `[0,0,255]` ,green is `[0,255,0]` ,blue is `[255,0,0]`.

How do other colors show?

Comment: You may use any [online color selector](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=color+selector&oq=color+selector&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.3646j0j1&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) to get RGB value of a specific color. Since OpenCV follows BGR convention but most of online or offline resource follow RGB convention, so simply swap the first and last value to get same results in OpenCV

Comment: Not really sure to understand your question, but you can use color picker (from google for example: https://www.google.fr/search?q=color+picker) to get rgb code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are some base colors that are good to know. For the rest you definitely should use a color mixer. Here is one that shows `rgb` and `bgr`  http://wamingo.net/rgbbgr/

**Base Colors:**

```
Blue:  [255, 0, 0]
Green: [0, 255, 0]
Red:   [0, 0, 255]
```

**Base Mixes:**

```
Yellow:  [0, 255, 255]
Magenta: [255, 0, 255]
Cyan:    [255, 255, 0]
```